# Replace Request.Url.Query value in Canonical URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, canonical-link

How do I replace the value of Request.Url.Query with String.Empty in the following snippet?

```
linkCanonical = "<link rel=\"Canonical\" href=\"" + Html.ViewContext.HttpContext.Request.Url + "\" />";
```

I know it isn't best practice. This is for a temporary fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove the entire querystring you could use

```
Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.AbsolutePath
```

This takes the host and ONLY the path information

Using `http://www.test.com/mypath.aspx?id=1` as an example it would give you `www.test.com/mypath.aspx`

Here is the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri(v=vs.110).aspx) as well to help you through the properties.